# How do I access any NOTEs that might appear while checking a package?

Tags: r, devtools

While running `R CMD check`, one can receive an Error, a Warning, or a NOTE.  I'd like to check if a NOTE was generated and if so access the contents of the NOTE programmatically.

My goal is to see if a NOTE was generated that indicates the submission does not yet exist on CRAN.  I know there are other ways to check that, but it seems a shame to reinvent the wheel since `devtools::check()` already generates a message if that is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, R is open source, and this comes from the file `src/library/tools/R/build.R`. So why not start there?

```
edd@max:~/src/debian/R/R-2.15.1/src/library/tools/R$ grep '"NOTE' build.R 
    resultLog(Log, "NOTE")
                     sprintf("NOTE: There were %d notes.\n",
                     sprintf("NOTE: There was 1 note.\n"))
edd@max:~/src/debian/R/R-2.15.1/src/library/tools/R$
```

Comment: That looks promising.  How do I access it in user-facing code, though?  I can't seem to find `resultLog` anywhere: `> findFn("resultLog")
found 0 matches`

Comment: Well then you don't get the green checkmark, now do you? I'm denying you that last .02% of your rep.

Comment: Not exactly increasing my motivation to ever help you again. :-)   Seriouly, `tools/R/build.R` is not meant to provide an API, so I think you should try to borrow / shadow / call / ... its tests and then user  the API components you need.

Comment: Aw shoot.  That's enough of an answer that I have to give you the green.